# особенности поведения android studio относительно deprecated?

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть приложение, написанное месяц-два назад. В нем используется метод `onCreateOptionsMenu`, все работает, отображается в редакторе как положено.

Сегодня при написании нового приложения и добавления этого же метода `onCreateOptionsMenu`, android studio отображает его как `deprecated`. Это такая особенность - успел написать до `deprecated`, редактор не акцентирует внимание на этом, даже если в текущий момент запуска редактора функции устарела или какой-то глюк?

P.S. в обоих случаях методы из androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.

Comment: Какие версии sdk в этих приложениях?

Comment: И какая версия androidx библиотек в обоих случаях?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  sdk в обоих случаях одинаковое, а вот версии androidx.fragment отличаются, в этом дело?

Comment: @Zmiter да, должно быть в этом дело)